# ¿Por que se cae mi servicio de GraphQL con postgresql?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, centos, graphql

Hemos desarrollado una solución muy básica de GraphQL v 15.3.0, que hace uso de pgPromise v 10.5.8 para conectarse a una BD postgresql, esta se ejecuta en en servidor Centos v 7 linux mediante node.js.
En ocasiones, 1 vez por semana, el servicio se detiene, aun que la demanda de consultas, no sobre pasa las 80 consultas por segundo, y un máximo de 508 registros tipo string.
A pesar de habilitar un log, y el monitoreo, no se ve mensaje de error cuando el servicio se detiene.
¿Cómo puedo saber el detalle del error que ocasiona que el servicio se detenga?
¿Hay alguna configuración recomendada para evitar esta falla en el servicio?

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y es difícil de responder porque, literalmente, cualquier cosa no relacionada con la soución puede estar deteniendo el servicio. Revisa los logs del sistema operativo para saber qué pasa. COnfirma además que el servicio esté en inicio automático; puede que haya alguna falla eléctrica o _cualquier otra cosa_ y el servicio no esté registrado para iniciarse al iniciar el OS. Más allá de eso, amplía la pregunta con detalles como la versión del OS y aclara cuál servicio se detiene (postgresql? la solución? no es claro)

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, el servicio que se detuvo fue el de Graphql, las versiones que estamos usando son: "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-import-node": "0.0.4",
    "graphql-iso-date": "^3.6.1",
    "graphql-merge-resolvers": "^1.1.16",
    "graphql-playground-middleware-express": "^1.7.18",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^6.2.4", Centos v 7. La BD no presenta error ni problema alguno, tampoco podemos ver nada en el log del servidor.

Comment: Ahí `journalctl -xe` puede ser tu nuevo mejor amigo. Más allá de eso, sólo lo que encuentres en `/var/log/` puede dar alguna pista. No sé con certeza qué parámetros de configuración puedan añadirse para diagnosticar graphql, pero posiblemente alguien con más conocimiento pueda aportar más comentarios... lamento no poder ayudar más

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré Alfabravo !!